Вылет Blender, при переходе в режимы Viewport или Shading
Когда я перехожу в режим Viewport или Shading у меня вылетает Blender, текущий проект не сохраняется, а проекты, сохраненные в этих режимах у меня вылетают не запустившись. Устройство: Huawei Mate Book D 15, AMD Radeon 15.6 IPS FHD.
Я нашел текстовый файл, образовавшийся при вылете проекта "м4а1": м4а1.crash. В нем, как написано в документации blender, содержится информация об ошибке, но сам я читать такие документы не умею. Подскажите пожалуйста, что это за ошибка?

«The transfer you requested has been deleted», поэтому всё относящееся к вопросу должно быть непосредственно в вопросе без сторонних ссылок

А как можно ссылку на текстовый документ прикрепить?

Очень странно видеть такой ответ на комментарий с фразой «без сторонних ссылок»

А вообще всё после строки Threads: скорее всего не очень интересно и в вопрос можно не добавлять

(ну а в любом случае это скорее всего к разработчикам Blender а не к нам)

С этим тоже проблема, я не могу найти, где можно обратиться в поддержку blender.. Меня постоянно отправляют в документации, а там нет технических вопросов вроде

https://developer.blender.org/docs/handbook/bug_reports/making_good_bug_reports/
